# SwiftUI EnvironmentObject lifespan

Tags: swift, swiftui

With SwiftUI, an environment object injected into the MainApp() view (WindowGroup) will retain all data until the app is fully closed out. (Data will be retained if you leave the app open in the background) If I am correct in my understanding, could this not be used as a sort of basic cache? The data is retained and only destroyed if the app is fully closed out, which is the same as NSCache. Is this how the lifespan of an environment object works?

Comment: Actually as for me it is self explaining by name "environment object" - object of environment lives as long as environment lives. Why NSCache? I don't see any relations. If you want something relative, then take ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment - much closer.

Comment: @Asperi right, and since the EO is injected into the main app view, the environment lives as long as any other data in the app can. (exception of coredata) I was comparing to NSCache because it lives as long as the app isnt fully closed out.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of.  The Environment object should live as long as the Environment exists (so in this case so long as the WindowGroup lives). In that sense it is a "global".

But that object will ALWAYS exist unless you do something unusual.  It will take up memory all the time.

`NSCache` implements a lot of behavior aimed at freeing up memory dynamically when there is memory pressure on the system.  The Environment is not going to implement any of that.

An `NSCache` is just an object, there's nothing inherit to `NSCache` that would make it behave as a global object - unless you store it in a global (static) variable.

You could put a cache in a SwiftUI environment anywhere in the scope of that Environment, but it's not particularly like an `NSCache` in my mind.